# CSS selector class throwing Typescript error when used in className attribute (using react)

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, components, styling

The string literals of styles.btn, styles .active and styles.inactive are throwing the error

I am using Vite, React, MUI, TypeScript

Property 'btn' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339) Any
Property 'active' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339) Any
Property 'inactive' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339) Any

Not exactly sure how to fix it because iv used css selector classes before without any issues

```
import styles from './Keyboard.css?inline';

<button
className={`${styles.btn} ${isActive ? styles.active : ''} ${isInactive ? styles.inactive : ''}`}
>
</button>
```

```
.btn {
    width: 100%;
    border: 3px solid black;
    background: none;
    aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: black;
}

.btn.active {
    background-color: hsl(200, 100%, 50%);
    color: white;
}

.btn.inactive {
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.btn:hover:not(:disabled),
.btn:focus:not(:disabled) {
    background-color: hsl(200, 100%, 75%);
}
```

Iv tried searching this issue online but it seems like this issue is very vague for a lot of different applications. Since I am also using MUI I have tried using their version of a Button but it just made things a bit more complex with the styling.

Comment: SOLVED!  

import './Keyboard.css';

changed ${styles.btn}, ${styles.active}, and ${styles.inactive} to regular strings 'btn', 'active', and 'inactive'

Making them strings instead of string literals fixed the issue